# Function throws error while using lapply, works fine otherwise

Tags: r, function, data.table, lapply

I have a list containing data tables. A sample list can be created using following code.

```
mydata=read.table(textConnection("
MSA_id   code variable Caucasian African.American Asian Hispanic Other
412 111011        1        64                2     0        0     0
412 111011        2       464               17     4       11     0
412 111021        1      2006               43    32       22    61
412 111021        2       559               18     6       10     0
412 111031        1        56                1     0        0     0
412 111031        2         1                0     0        0     0"),header=TRUE) 
setDT(mydata) 
z = split(mydata,mydata$code)

> z[1:2]
$`111011`
   MSA_id   code variable Caucasian African.American Asian Hispanic Other
1:    412 111011        1        64                2     0        0     0
2:    412 111011        2       464               17     4       11     0

$`111021`
   MSA_id   code variable Caucasian African.American Asian Hispanic Other
1:    412 111021        1      2006               43    32       22    61
2:    412 111021        2       559               18     6       10     0
```

I want to reformat elements of this list (data.tables) based on their values. 
From my code, the elements of reformatted list should like this:
First Element:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]   64    2
[2,]  464   32
```

Second Element

```
   Caucasian African.American Asian Hispanic
1:      2006               43    32       22
2:       559               18     6       10
```

Algorithm for this is:

1. Remove first 3 columns and the last column.
2. If minimum value of Caucasian is 0, or sum of minimum values of rest
   3 (that is:African.American,Asian,Hispanic) categories is 0, then
   set the element as NA.
3. Else if minimum of African.American is 0 or sum of minimum values of
   Asian and Hispanic is 0, then sum up  African.American, Asian, and
   Hispanic as single category.
4. Else if minimum value of Asian is 0 or minimum value of Hispanic is
   0, sum up Asian and Hispanic as single category.
5. Else keep the format as it is.

I created a function to do it. When I use this function on one element at a time, it works fine, but when I use lapply, it breaks.

```
formatTable <- function(z){ 
    a = z[[1]]
    b = a[,list(Caucasian,African.American,Asian,Hispanic),] # Deleting columns 1,2,3 and 8

    if ( min(b$Caucasian) == 0) {
       formatTable=NA
    } else if ( (min(b$African.American) + min(b$Asian) + min(b$Hispanic)) == 0) {
       formatTable=NA
    } else if ( (min(b$African.American) == 0) | (min(b$Asian) + min(b$Hispanic)==0)) {
       formatTable = cbind(b$Caucasian, b$African.American+b$Asian+b$Hispanic)
    } else if ( min(b$Asian)==0 | min(b$Hispanic)==0) {
       formatTable = cbind(b$Caucasian, b$African.American, b$Asian+b$Hispanic)
    } else
       formatTable = b
}
```

Using this function, `t1=formatTable(z[1])` and `t2=formatTable(z[2])` gives correct result, however if I use `tbls = lapply(z[1:2],formatTable)` it says `Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : object 'Caucasian' not found`.

Please help on why lapply throws this error.

Comment: The error comes from `a = z[[1]]`, replacing it by `a = z` removes the error and produces expected results.

Comment: read about list indexing with `[` and `[[`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I will definitely read about it. I thought that z[[1]] gives me just the element of the list (data table) which I need to work upon. Seems like I need to know more.

Comment: I guess the problem is understanding what `lapply` does, then.